# How to disable the microphone of a Logitech BRIO webcam under Linux?

Tags: drivers, audio, video, input, camera

I have a Logitech BRIO webcam, which has a microphone that I never use. To avoid confusion, I would like to disable it on the lowest possible level. Can I somehow tell Linux to never load the driver for this audio input device, without disabling the video input device?

Comment: AFAIK there's a single driver which provides video/audio input, so it's hard to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user space device manager "[udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev)" for the Linux kernel can block drivers from being active on specific devices. To use its functionality, you need to identify the device you want to block, create a rule prohibiting its driver from being active, reload the udev rules and restart your machine.

Get the device ID `046d:085e` like so:

```bash
$ lsusb | grep "Logitech BRIO"
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:085e Logitech, Inc. Logitech BRIO
```

Create an udev rule

```bash
sudo vim /etc/udev/rules.d/90-block-brio-sound.rules
```

Paste these contents into the file:

```
# Block Logitech BRIO webcam microphone
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", DRIVER=="snd-usb-audio", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="085e", ATTR{authorized}="0"
```

Reload the udev rules:

```bash
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

To apply the configuration to the running system, restart your computer:

```bash
sudo reboot
```

Comment: This works for me. After the restart, I no longer see the microphone of the Logitech BRIO webcam appearing in the GNOME Shell's system sound input settings.

Comment: Works for me too.  thank you.

Comment: Thanks for verifying, @dementedhedgehog.